# client request body is buffered to a temporary file

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer, amazon-elb

I am using nginx as a load balancer I keep seeing the messages above. I keep uping the client_body_buffer_size, proxy_buffer_size and proxy_buffers but it doesn't seem to make a difference. What could be happening here?

Comment: That appears to be an informational warning, not an error.  See https://serverfault.com/q/511789/153161

Comment: I have seen this error in nginx error.log and this is happening due to load balancer. I have two load balancers in my aws server. 1. classic and 2. appliation all requests working fine with classic load balancer but getting failed with application load balancer. I m looking for the reason that why this is happening.